# How do I completely uninstall Deno and its cached packages

Tags: deno

I want to uninstall Deno and all of its cached packages. Where it caches its packages? And **how to make sure that all of cached packages are uninstalled** before installing a new version of Deno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here are deno cache locations on your system if you are used default install location:

> By default, `DENO_DIR` is located in `$HOME/.deno`. However, the user
>   could also change its location by modifying the `$DENO_DIR` environment
>   variable. Explicitly setting `DENO_DIR` is recommended in production.

Also, this is hiararchy structure:

```
 DIRECTORIES
gen/: Cache for files compiled to JavaScript
deps/: Cache for remote url imported files
  |__ http/: For http imports
  |__ https/: For https imports

# FILES
deno_history.txt: History of Deno REPL
```

So, in general I think that you can clear your deno installation with simple deleting folder `$HOME/.deno` on your computer. Also, you could try simple `uninstall` command which depends on your system and install tool you use here are info about installing deno with different tools so try use your tool and correct `uninstall` command https://github.com/denoland/deno_install

Answer (score 3):

To uninstall Deno, remove the directories `~/.deno` and `~/.cache/deno`. The cache directory may be in on another location, run `deno info`, to figure out where it is.

To upgrade Deno to the latest version, run `deno upgrade`.

To reload all cached modules for your app, run `deno cache --reload myapp.ts`.

See also `deno --help` or `deno <command> --help`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need to uninstall deno if you want to update it. Deno already provides a command to upgrade to an existing version of deno.

For example, at the time of writing [v1.0.5](https://github.com/denoland/deno/releases/tag/v1.0.5) is the latest release.
As specified you can just use this command to upgrade deno -

```
deno upgrade --version 1.0.5
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but does this command fix the cached packages? I need a completely fresh environment i.e., by removing all cached packages.